# How to resolve 'ImportError: No module named querystring'?

Tags: dependencies, plone, versioning, product, pinning

When installing a product with several dependencies in a Plone-4.1.6-site, I get on site creation:

```
2013-03-06 09:18:38 ERROR Zope.SiteErrorLog 1362557918.010.833996902243 http://myserver.de:8182/@@plone-addsite
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module Products.CMFPlone.browser.admin, line 204, in __call__
  Module Products.CMFPlone.factory, line 100, in addPloneSite
  Module Products.GenericSetup.tool, line 353, in runAllImportStepsFromProfile
   - __traceback_info__: profile-aip.policy:default
  Module Products.GenericSetup.tool, line 1123, in _runImportStepsFromContext
  Module Products.GenericSetup.tool, line 1036, in _doRunImportStep
   - __traceback_info__: plone.app.registry
  Module plone.app.registry.exportimport.handler, line 35, in importRegistry
  Module plone.app.registry.exportimport.handler, line 74, in importDocument
  Module plone.app.registry.exportimport.handler, line 232, in importRecords
  Module zope.dottedname.resolve, line 38, in resolve
ImportError: No module named querystring
```

As the error-message indicates a conflict in p.a.registry, I tried to fetch the newest version (1.2.2, right now) with 'bin/buildout -n', still an older version (1.0.1) is picked.

So, I pinned it down in buildout's config, but then get:

> The version, 1.0.1, is not consistent with the requirement,
>   'plone.app.registry==1.2.2'. While:   Installing instance. Error: Bad
>   version 1.0.1

Assuming one of the deps pins p.a.registry down, I grepped the eggs-cache like this:

```
grep -r --include=requires.txt "plone.app.registry" /path/to/eggs
```

With no result, in terms of, that the declarations only require 'greater than'-versions.

Has anyone a clue, how I could proceed to resolve this?

**Edit:**
The config included via the extends-part (http://dist.plone.org/release/4.1.6/versions.cfg), contains the line I was looking for, didn't think of that in first place, clicked 'close', now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package you are trying to install is missing a dependency. The problem is not with plone.app.registry.

You might be able to solve your problem by adding plone.app.querystring to the list of packages in your buildout; however, it's possible the addon you're installing is missing other dependencies also.

Comment: Running buildout with the "-v" (or even "-vvv") flag may help you determine the problem addon.

Comment: @vangheem: Thanks, I built a new instance with no probs so far, but your answer is generally helpful (provide the missing module instead of searching in the product producing the error-message), accepted :)

Comment: @SteveM: I know about the '-v' option, but of course it cannot be pointed out often enough :)